# WooCommerce Product Vendors - update taxonomy custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**This is all in regards to WooCommerce and the Product Vendor extension.**

In my function I'm creating new taxonomy terms (Product Vendors) each time my gravity form is submitted, however there are additional custom fields which I want to populate.

The following works to update the term name and slug. I am trying to update fields such as the PayPal email, Vendor Logo etc.

For this test I've manually set the variables below.

```
$user = 'formname';
$email    = 'example@gmail.com';
$description = 'this is a test';

$return = wp_insert_term(
  $user, // the term
  'wcpv_product_vendors', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> $description,
    'slug' => $user,
  )
);

// Update vendor data
$vendor_data['paypal_email'] = $email; // The email used for the account will be used for the payments
$vendor_data['commission']   = '50'; // The commission is 50% for each order

update_option( 'shop_vendor_' . $return['term_id'], $vendor_data );

// Update vendor data
$vendor_data['paypal_email'] = $email; // The email used for the account will be used for the payments
$vendor_data['commission']   = '50'; // The commission is 50% for each order
$vendor_data['admins'][]     = $customer_id; // The registered account is also the admin of the vendor

update_option( 'shop_vendor_' . $return['term_id'], $vendor_data );
```

The function runs when the form is submitted, it's just not adding data into the vendor taxonomy fields.

[image]

[image]

**Full Code**

```
//Woocommerce - ETSY - Import
function create_vendor_form( $entry, $form ) {

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// GET DATA FROM API

$user = rgar( $entry, '1' );
$email    = rgar( $entry, '2' );
$description = rgar( $entry, '3' );

$return = wp_insert_term(
  $user, // the term
  'wcpv_product_vendors', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> $description,
    'slug' => $user,
  )
);

// Update vendor data
$vendor_data['paypal_email'] = $email; // The email used for the account will be used for the payments
$vendor_data['commission']   = '50'; // The commission is 50% for each order
$vendor_data['admins'][]     = $customer_id; // The registered account is also the admin of the vendor

update_option( 'shop_vendor_' . $return['term_id'], $vendor_data );

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// end GET DATA FROM API

}
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_2', 'create_vendor_form', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first add the data to the $vendor_data array and then apply it using the following:

```
//Add the data to the array
$vendor_data['paypal'] = $email;
$vendor_data['profile'] = $description;

//Update the term meta with the above values.
update_term_meta($return['term_id'], 'vendor_data', $vendor_data);
```

Comment: How did you know it was specifically 'profile' you needed to use, for example I may have guessed 'vendor_profile' or something.